# find 2 identical words in one line and select only the number

Tags: sed, grep

I have an html file with numbers. I need to select only numbers. How to get only number 258108 and 263431?

```
view 
258108
263431
```

```
<p class="list-item">
    <span style="margin-left: 20px" class="padding"></span>
    <span class="icon left drop-down-icon" onclick="toggle(this, '15CF78F7-594A-4A8A-9DDC-E4896E9DB430')"></span>
    testIT: C258108, testIT: C263431 (1m19s)
    <span class="icon paperclip-icon" style="display: inline-block"></span>
  </p>
```

I did

`sed -n -e 's/^.*testIT: C//p' | sed -r 's/ .+//'`

but I only get the last one `263431`

Comment: Does [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1505375/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b8-2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b) answer your question?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why is `view` a number? Why isn't `20px` a number? Are you parsing html? Why don't you use a proper html parser?

Comment: could you try passing the file name in the parameter `sed -n -e 's/^.*testIT: C//p' <filename> | sed -r 's/ .+//'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not substituting pattern occurrences, perhaps **grep** would be a better choice for you.

Assuming that you are looking to capture numbers following `C` before `testIT:` You could try this grep/cut combination:

```
cat input.txt | grep -o -E 'testIT: C[0-9]+'|cut -d " " -f2|cut -c 2-
```

**grep** arguments used:

- -o shows only the matching portions of the input
- -E enables extended regex use

The first **cut** command simply extracts the second value after `testIT:` and the second removes the prepended `C` character